# How to find call an external function from a GUI in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have an external function (myfun.m) which will generate 4 images. I want to use a textbox in a GUI to give the function the input parameters (e.g. the name of the original picture), but I have no clue how I can run myfun.m in my GUI. PLease help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend having a different textbox for each input to your function. For example if your function asks for 4 inputs, I would have four textboxes. This will avoid pain on the user's end to format their text input a certain way, as well as pain on your end on parsing a long text string into several inputs.

Second, if your function is within MATLAB's path, then you can call that directly from your GUI no problem just as you would any of MATLAB's built-in functions. You probably want to make a push-button that has a callback to execute that functions.

The way the callback for this function should look is to l

Comment: I do the following, axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(result.Step1_original_image); BUT MATLAB says ??? Error using ==> axes  ;Invalid object handle